# Type of *the* discrete sine transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

When one refers to "the" discrete cosine transform (DCT), it is generally assumed that one means the type II DCT, where the input array $x_k$ ($0 \leq k < N-1$) is even about $k=-1/2$ and $k=N-1/2$.

Is there a similar convention for "the" discrete sine transform?  MATLAB defaults to type I, while *Mathematica* prefers type II.  The FFTW docs are silent on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *eight* kinds of DCTs, and *eight* kinds of DSTs. The classification is due to [Wang and Hunt](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0096-3003%2885%2990008-6).

You'd do well to just specify the DTT type explicitly; DCT-II being the "default" DCT is due to its ubiquity (e.g. JPEG). Personally, I tend to use types I, II, and III of DST and DCT in my work, and I think it is not unhelpful to always append the type to the DCT or DST that you're using.

Comment: Just to be painfully explicit.  DCT-II is the default because of its ubiquity. However, the DST (all eight of them) has not developed a similar convention.

Comment: Yep, nice summary. :)